terraform insists that a resource already exists, says it doesn't when i try to import it
i keep running into the same problem when i try to create azure resources with terraform: terraform insists that some resources already exist.
It tells me to import them.
If i do, it tells me i need to define them first because i never manage to get the correct name iguess.
For instance, i create resource groups using a module. i pas the name to the module and then it is created in the module using the name "this".
I do not know what name to use to address this for the import.
module "example-resource-group" {
  source   = "./modules/resource-group"

  name     = "rg-example-${var.environment}"
  location = var.location
  tags     = local.tags
}

and then in ./modules/resource-group/main.tf
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "this" {
  location = var.location
  name     = var.name
  tags     = var.tags
}

What would be the name of this in the end? How can i import this?
And why does it always say the resource exists if i start with a green field?

For import you would use the whole path, let's call it that way, to the resource you want to import, i.e: module.example-resource-group.azurerm_resource_group.this.

module importing is a bit different than the regular resource importing in terraform. @Andresch Serj

Have you verified the below approach? @Andresch Serj


What would be the name of this in the end? How can I import this? And why does it always say the resource exist?

When you are trying to create a resource which has already existed in Azure environment even though it was not creating by you or by terraform, it will show a warning message as shown in the below format.

In this kind of scenarios, terraform import You can import the resource into current terraform state configuration to deal with the resources when it is required.
Saying that, resources and modules both can be imported with terraform import command with a slight change.
In your case, when you are importing a module, you need to follow module.modulename.resourceprovidertype.resource this format.
module.example-resource-group.azurerm_resource_group.this
Note: Here, "this" is referring to the resource group resource under module configuration .tf file.
Refer Blog for relevant information in a more detailed way.
I have tried to import an already existed resource group in my terraform environment and was successfully imported as shown below.
Syntax:
terraform import module.example-resource-group.azurerm_resource_group.example <resource ID>
Note: The name of the resource within the module is "example", so when I was calling the module, it refers to that resource in the above given module format.
terraform import module.example-resource-group.azurerm_resource_group.example /subscriptions/subscriptionID/resourceGroups/Jahnavi


Once it is imported, verify it is there in the terraform.tfstatefile configuration:

Also, you can use terraform state list command to verify the terraform state configuration imported resources.

